# left operand must be l-value in C

Tags: c, lvalue

I have following function copied from C book, and I can't figure out why is if condition throwing error.

```
int strindex(char s[], char t[]) {
int index,k;

for (int i = 0; s[i] != '\n'; i++) {
    for (int j = i, k = 0; t[k] != '\0' && s[j] == t[k]; j++, k++)
        continue;
    if (k > 0 && t[k] = '\0')
        return i;

    }
}
```

Why is

```
if (k>0)
```

giving '=' left operand must be l-value

Comment: `=` in `t[k] = '\0'` must be a `==`.

Comment: Damn I missed that one ... Thanks for help

Comment: Note that if you had written `if (k > 0 && (t[k] = '\0'))`, the code would still have been logically incorrect, but you wouldn't have gotten an error message, since `t[k]` *is* an lvalue.

Answer (score 3):

Your compiler apparently parses the expression

```
k > 0 && t[k] = '\0'
```

as

```
(k > 0 && t[k]) = '\0'
```

I.e. it thinks that you are trying to assign `'\0'` to the result of `k > 0 && t[k]`. The latter is not an lvalue. You cannot assign anything to it.

Apparently you code is not "copied" from a book, as you seem to claim. I strongly suspect the book used a `==` operator where you used a `=`.

---

To be pedantic, in this case you are dealing with a well-known and rather strange behavior of GNU compilers (and some other C compilers as well). The *official* C grammar is written in a very particular way that prevents expressions like

```
k > 0 && t[k] = '\0'
```

from being parsed at all. The C grammar for assignment expression is

```
assignment-expression:
  conditional-expression
  unary-expression assignment-operator assignment-expression
```

which makes it impossible to smuggle a `&&` into the left-hand side of assignment, unless you explicitly enclose the left-hand side into `()`.

In other words, the "left operand must be l-value" is a misleading error message. The proper interpretation of this situation is that in C language this expression is simply grammatically incorrect. It is simply *not parsable at all*. From the formal language point of view, this expression is pure meaningless mumbo-jumbo.

By issuing a bogus "left operand must be l-value" diagnostic the compiler formally satisfies the requirements of the standard (it has to issue *some* diagnostic, no matter what it says), but, again, the formal problem in your original code has nothing to do with any "lvalues".

Answer (score 1):

In the function

```
int strindex(char s[], char t[]) {
int index,k;

for (int i = 0; s[i] != '\n'; i++) {
    for (int j = i, k = 0; t[k] != '\0' && s[j] == t[k]; j++, k++)
        continue;
    if (k > 0 && t[k] = '\0')
        return i;

    }
}
```

there are declared two variables `k`. The first one is declared in this line

```
int index,k;
^^^      ^^^
```

and the second one is declared in this line

```
for (int j = i, k = 0; t[k] != '\0' && s[j] == t[k]; j++, k++)
     ^^^       ^^^
```

In this statement

```
if (k > 0 && t[k] = '\0')
```

there is used the first one uninitialized variable `k`. Moreover it seems due to the typo

```
if (k > 0 && t[k] = '\0')
                 ^^^^
```

that is there is used the assignment operator instead of the comparison operator the condition in the if statement looks like

```
if ( ( k > 0 && t[k] ) = '\0')
```

and as such is invalid.

I think you just mean

```
if (k > 0 && t[k] == '\0')
                  ^^^
```

though in any case this statement is invalid because the variable `k` is not initialized.

Comment: *ihst* was a very cool typo.  :)

Comment: @giusti Does it has any meaning?:)